# Difference jsonp and simple get request (cross domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jsonp

I have to send (and receive) certain data to a server using JQuery and JSON.
Works so far, but not cross domain, and it has to be cross domain.

I looked how to solve this and found JSONP. As far as I see, using JSONP I have to send the callback and the data using GET (JQuery allows to use "POST" as method, but when I inspect web traffic I see it is sending actually GET and everyting as parameter).

JSONP also requires changes in the server, because they are expecting a POST request with JSON data, and they have to implement something to process the JSONP GET request.

So I'm wondering what's the difference between this and sending the data as key value parameters in GET request?

Is the difference the possibility to use a callback? Or what exactly?

Sorry a bit lost... thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSONP is not a form submission. It is a way of telling the server via a GET request how to generate the content for a script tag. The data returned is a payload of JavaScript (not just JSON!) with a function call to a callback which you (by convention) reference in the GET request.

JSONP works because it is a hack that doesn't use AJAX. It isn't AJAX and you should not confuse it for such because it *does not* use a XMLHttpRequest at any point to send the data. That is how it gets around the Same Origin Policy.

Depending on the browsers you have to support, you can implement Cross-Origin Resource Sharing headers on the server side which will let you use normal AJAX calls across trusted domains. Most browsers (IE8, Firefox 3.5+, etc.) will support CORS.

Another solution you can use if you don't want to use CORS or JSONP is to write a PHP script or Java servlet that will act as a proxy. That's as simple as opening a new connection from the script, copying all of the incoming parameters from your AJAX code onto the request and then dumping the response back at the end of your script.

Comment: If it's that simple to add headers on the server why everybody bothers with JSONP? As far as I understand with JSONP there's also necessary to make changes in the server

Comment: The proxy solution is not usable in my case, because I need the script to be testable in localhost, and not everybody testing my script in localhost is wanting to install the proxy...

Comment: Ok, I found an explanation about differences between JSONP and CORS here http://www.json-p.org/ it seems CORS is not "that simple"

Comment: It *is* Ajax. Ajax is a catchall name for all the techniques that involve communicating with the server without leaving the page.

Comment: This is useful information but doesn't anwer the question directly. I (now) think the difference is that a simple GET request using ajax would also not work, because of same origin policy. With JSONP it works because it's a GET request made by the broser when fetching injected script. And well, yes, that's not ajax, from a strict point of view.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer that worked for me with the cross-domain issue and JSON (not JSONP).
I simply used:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

inside my json file (file.php) and called it like this:

```
var serviceURL = 'http://your-domain.com/your/json/location.php'
$.getJSON(serviceURL,function (data) {
   var entries = data;
   //do your stuff here using your entries in json
});
```

BTW: this is a receiving process, not sending.

Comment: I think this is CORS. It's not exactly what I'm asking, but thanks anyways for answering.

Comment: I have implemented this solution to my native mobile application using jQuery Mobile and it was aproved by apple. All my data are JSON format generated by php files from an database stored on a server. I was in a struggle to find a solution that worked for cross-domain scripting and not to change all my JSON requests into JSONP.

Comment: Inserting the header script into my php files worked like a charm and now i have the posibility to request my json data from all over the internet, even mobile native app. From my point of view this is the best solution because i can modify de php.json data generator not to be affected by hacks like SQL injection or others. If you like, i can post an php example of how to maintain security over SQL callbacks and return a very nice structured JSON data that you can use (call from) everywhere!